# What is $\gcd (x^{3}+6x^{2}+11x+6,x^{3}+1)$

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

When applying straight-forward Euclid's algorithm the result have fractional coefficients, but by factoring linear terms you get $x+1$. Which answer is right?

Comment: Assuming that you are looking for the gcd in a ring like $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ or $\Bbb{R}[x]$ the gcd is only unique up to a (non-zero) constant multiple. So for example $x+1$ and $7x+7$ are the same gcd - both are correct. This is because the constant (here $7$) is a unit in that ring. For the same reason both $2$ and $-2$ could be called $\gcd(4,-6)$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$. All because $-1$ is a unit. We can choose to normalize the answer to be a positive integer or a monic polynomial. But then we need to include a normallization step into the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: In light of the above comment, all you need to do therefore, is to check whether  your polynomial with fractional  coefficients, and $x+1$, are related by being constant multiples.. If not, then we can correct your approach. It seems that $x+1$ is correct, so if at all, only the other answer can be incorrect. Please post your answer below afterwards.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you refer me to a theorem which implies we can omit coefficients which are units in the ring? When deviding the remainder with its coefficient $\frac{91}{36}$ the invert coefficient obviously shows up before the nom. and denom. polynomials, but what exactly gives me the "right" to then just omit this inverse coefficient?

Comment: No theorem needed. [Wikipedia's general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#General_definition) states that explicitly. More generally, we view gcd in a PID as a generator of the ideal generated by those two things. And such a generator automatically has unit ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I get. Note the check at the very end, in order to express the gcd as a linear combination of the initial terms, the coefficients do get denominators, your 91.  Let me paste that here:

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 91 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 25 }{ 91 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x  - 1 \right)  $$

OR

$$  - \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 91 }  \right)  +  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 25 }{ 91 }  \right)  = \; \;   x+1   $$

===========================================================

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) } +  \left(  6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 5 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 5 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 36 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 91 x  + 91 }{ 36 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 91 x  + 91 }{ 36 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 216 x  + 180 }{ 91 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left( 1  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 36 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 25 }{ 36 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 36 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 216 x  + 180 }{ 91 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 36 x^{2}  + 180 x  + 216 }{ 91 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 36 x^{2}  - 36 x  + 36 }{ 91 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 91 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 25 }{ 91 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 11 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  - 11 }{ 91 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 25 }{ 91 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x  - 1 \right)  $$

Comment: it's rather naive but to multiply the whole second expression by 36 to get the form $216x^{2}+396x+180=q\left(91x+91\right)+36r$ was quite helpful, thanks for that also!

Answer (score 0):

$(x^3+6x^2+11x+6,x^3+1)=((x+1)(x^2-x+1),(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)) = (x+1)((x^2-x+1),(x+2)(x+3)) = (x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the gcd in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ following Jyrki Lahtonen's comments. 
So, just to see what happens, lets work in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, also a unique factorization domain. Note that If $(a,c)=1$ then $(a,b)=(a,cb)$

$$(x^3+6x^2+11x+6, x^3+1)=(6x^2+11x+5, x^3+1)$$
$$=(6x^2+11x+5, 6x^3+6), \text{since} (11x+5,6)=1$$
$$=(6x^2+11x+5, 11x^2+5x-6)$$
$$=(66x^2+121x+55, 66x^2+30x-36)$$
$$=(91x+91, 66x^2+30x-36)$$
$$=(x+1, 11x^2+5x-6)$$
$$=(x+1, 6x+6)$$
$$=x+1$$

Answer (score 0):

Both methods may agree (depending on the "fractional coefficients" you got).  When it comes to factoring any constant times a polynomial $P(x)$ is the same as $P(x)$ because you have the same roots.  For instance, there is no substantial difference between $x+1$ and $(36/91)(x+1)=(36/91)x+(36/91)$ because they both have a single, nondegenerate root at $x=-1$.